# How did John Wick get stabbed with a champagne glass in chapter one?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick

As the title implies, I'm confused as to how John Wick got stabbed in the Red Circle bar. Beforehand it shows him suiting up - the area he is stabbed is seemingly covered.

I know bulletproof vests aren't explicitly stab-proof, but compared to a sharp knife I'd expect a champagne bottle to be negligible for a bulletproof vest to stop, even a thin woven material like his as shown to be.

Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything, I think it's an inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

Bullet proof vest cover front (and some back) part of the body. And they are (when not made out of really stab proof material) very pierceable. 
Let's say I've seen people stabbed with tulip (ths is wha you call the item you're left when you break the botom of the bottle) through winter jacket, heat vest, sweater, thermal t-shirt. Broken bottle have many piercing parts. Each one have usually 5 cutting edges so it's quite easy to cut and then spread the material.

Comment: Not sure how large his vest was, but the stab was quite low into the stomach. It oculd very well be below the vest and hence there was just the shirt in the way of the bottle